# Can the Firefox menu bar be hidden?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, fullscreen

As a recent convert to Firefox I'm still trying to customize my environment.  I'd like to hide the Firefox menu bar.  I see options for hiding the navigation bar and the bookmarks tool bar, but nothing for the menu.

Full screen mode effectively hides the menu bar, but I would still like to see the other tool bars.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use this add-on: [Hide Menubar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hidemenubar/).

[image]

Comment: Great add-on! Press `ALT` to show and hide the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to press Alt all the time to access the menu, I use **[Tiny Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1455)**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker posted some tips about minimizing firefox's chrome.  [Take a look](http://lifehacker.com/software/firefox/geek-to-live--consolidate-firefoxs-chrome-210542.php)